# How do I disable the daylight cycle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map with permanent night. I've tried `gamerule dodaylightcycle false` and `gamerule doDayLightCycle false` but neither option works. How do I disable the daylight cycle and set the map to permanent night?

Answer (score 7):

You almost had it right: The "L" in "Daylight" is not capitalized:

```
/gamerule doDaylightCycle false
```

For the future you can better enter `/gamerule do` and see what autocomplete gives you.